# What is Z_ENT column in SQLite database that gets created by Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

When you use Core Data with SQLite database as underlying data store, core data will autogenerate some columns...

One of them is "Z_ENT"  and another is "Z_OPT"

I believe "Z_OPT" is for how many times the record has been altered.  Can anyone tell me what Z_ENT is for?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would they track Z_OPT? Who is using that data?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

"Z_PK is the unique id for each, Z_ENT is their entity id (same as what’s listed in the Z_PRIMARYKEY table"

From [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data)

Comment: Very valuable (even now) :)

Comment: As a SQLite layperson with dated MySQL knowledge pointedly poking around, this answer didn't really tell me what the purpose of z_ent was. However, according to another site I found, it says z_ent is a table ID, which makes much more sense to me. Found here: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki//Applications/MobileNotes.app